# How do I export Entityform submissions to CSV?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I see that it is possible to bulk download Entityform submissions to a CSV file.

How do I do it? I don't see a "Download as CSV" button anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I installed Views Data Export *after* installing Entityforms.

I had to go to the Entityforms view (which is the automatically generated admin view showing the form's submissions), click the arrow next to "Edit View Name/Description" and click "Revert View".

Now a CSV/XML export button shows up on the Submissions view, and I can export happily.